# Using .ajaxQueue questions

Tags: jquery, ajax

It was suggested to me to use ajaxQueue to solve the problems I was having with loading text with ajax in the order I need it to load.

I gave a look at the script, I tried using is, but I can't seem to figure out how it's supposed to work.

How do I transform something that looks like this

```
    $.ajax({
    url: 'text/example.txt',
    success: function(text){
            document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = document.getElementById("main").innerHTML + text;
    }
});
```

To use ajaxqueue?

Is there any simple way to do it without rewriting the whole thing?

Please don't flag this as duplicate I read any thread I could find but I have no idea what to do

Comment: i can't see what order you are talking about?

Comment: basically I have a bunch of pieces of code like the one I posted in OP that are loaded one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery then you can merge two html by this way.

```
$('#html-1').prepend($('#html-2').html()).prev().remove();
```

In your case,

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'text/example.txt',
    success: function(text){
           $('#main').prepend(text).prev().remove();
    }
});
```